# Finding closest K elements on a 2d plane

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, dynamic-programming

Eg: Input: In a 2d plane, say I have some N number of points (a,b) (c,d) ....... N. 
Our algorithm needs to find out closest K elements, say K=4, then we need to find out four closely located neighbors. To be more clear: If the solar system is a 2d plane, all the planets are points on it, we need to return earth and venus (assuming earth and venus closest two than any other pair of planets ) whereas K =2 in this case.
I have searched the internet only to find first K points w.r.t origin, but in this question, the points can be anywhere in the 2d plane. I heard from someone we need to use Dynamic programming for this.

Comment: Input: In a 2d plane, say I have some N number of points (a,b) (c,d) ....... N . 
My algorithm needs to find out closest K elements(say K=4) then we need to find out four closely located neighbors. 
To be more clear: If the solar system is a 2d plane, all the planets are points on it, we need to return earth and venus (assuming earth and venus closest two then any other pair of planets ) whereas K =2 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *KD Tree* does the job.

It's a geometric data structure that can find nearest neighbors efficiently by cutting the search space similarly to a binary search. It has some interesting practical applications, for example, it is used in implementations of the KNN algorithm, which is a machile learning algorithm based on finding nearest neighbors of given points on a Kd hyper plane.

You can find a simple explanation about the structure here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: Thanks Lucas, this is much helpful.